# How to create repository and push code from server/cpanel to bitbucket

Tags: git, ssh, server, bitbucket

We have wordpress website and hosted on server. We got to know that `GIT` us already installed on our server. We checked it as well by ran command `git --version`

What we are trying is to push code from server to bit bucket via command line/SSH.

We have followed following steps but unable to complete process :

1. Created account on bit bucket.
2. Created blank repository
3. Run command `git init <directory>`, We can see **.git** file into server where code exists. i.e [public_html/website/]
4. Run command `git add`
5. Now really confuse that what we should do next? Should we create clone or add remote origin?

From SSH, We have run command `git remote add origin user@bitbucket.org: pathtogit`

But above command is not working[It returns me usage of command].

Have done lot of research for easy steps to push code from server to bitbucket but every search result has diff. methods and I am confused.

If command line is difficult then any easy way to achieve it via sourcetree?

Comment: *But above command is not working.* ... what does not work? What errors you can see?

Comment: Alternatively, if there is no code there and you're just setting up, create a new repo on bitbucket and clone it to your server. We will need to see what error you're getting to help.

Comment: @Jakuje - Updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git remote add origin user@bitbucket.org: pathtogit
```

You are having one space between host and path. The correct command should look like this:

```
git remote add origin user@bitbucket.org:pathtogit
```

Comment: Here **pathtogit** means path of bit bucket repository or path of my server where .git file created?

Comment: The path on git server (bitbucket repository).

Comment: I see then where I should specify path of my server from where I want to push code.

Comment: Your code on your server is in the current working directory (previously added with `git add`).

Comment: So I should run command **git add** from ssh and from directory where **.git** file is placed?

Comment: Usually yes. Also the `git remote` is a good idea to run from that directory.

Comment: I see. fine. I will try and back.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do after step 4, is to add the remote repo:

git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git

Then `git status` to see if the files you want to push to bitbucket are there. If they're not:

```
git add --all
```

Then you commit your changes:

```
git commit -m "My first commit"
```

And finally you push to the server:

```
git push origin master
```

Where `master` is your branch.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and tested this and it works.

login using ssh
go to public_html directory

Now type the following command

```
git clone repository_name
```

where repository_name  is your bitbucket or github repo name

after you clone the repo you will get a a git folder

copy the .git file in you main root folder.

```
 git add .     
 git commit -m "message" 
 git pull origin master
 git push -u origin master
```

where master is your branch